# XML Linq query not working

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

I'm pretty new to using LINQ so I'm not entirely sure of all the correct syntaxes etc.

Here's what I've got so far

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Bookings>
    <Booking BookingNumber="300067649">
        <FLIGHTS>
            <FlightGroups>
                <FlightGroup ID="1 ">
                    <Flights>
                        <Flight ID="1">
                            <ADULTS>1</ADULTS>
                            <DEPARTURE_DATE>18/02/2006</DEPARTURE_DATE>
                        </Flight>
                    </Flights>
                </FlightGroup>
            </FlightGroups>
        </FLIGHTS>
    </Booking>
</Bookings>
```

I get this from a web service controlled by an outside company so i'm unable to change the syntax

Here's the LINQ i'm using in my .Net code

```
Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load(New StringReader(xmlstring))
Dim tests As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From el In
    root.Elements("Booking").Elements("FLIGHTS").Descendants() 
    Where CType(el.Element("DEPARTURE_DATE"), DateTime).Date <= DateTime.Now.Date

For Each el As XElement In tests
    Response.Write(el)
Next
```

The string `xmlstring` being the XML from above.

The problem is that this is giving me an error which is:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element
```

Basically i'm trying to select all flights that are before todays date and just can't seem to get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: FYI, you can use XElement.Parse() instead of Load when loading a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your current culture, `18/02/2006` may not be convertible to a `DateTime` (the day comes before the month. If you're in the US, the month should come before the day).

This throws an error (I'm in the USA).

```
var d1 = DateTime.Parse("18/02/2006");
```

This works:

```
var d2 = DateTime.Parse("02/18/2006");
```

I just tried the test below, and everything worked as expected (I changed the format of the date). You may have to provide a format provider for converting the date.

```
var str = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Bookings>
    <Booking BookingNumber=""300067649"">
        <FLIGHTS>
            <FlightGroups>
                <FlightGroup ID=""1"">
                    <Flights>
                        <Flight ID=""1"">
                            <ADULTS>1</ADULTS>
                            <DEPARTURE_DATE>02/18/2006</DEPARTURE_DATE>
                        </Flight>
                    </Flights>
                </FlightGroup>
            </FlightGroups>
        </FLIGHTS>
    </Booking>
</Bookings>
";
var xel = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(str);

var flights = xel.Descendants("Flight");
var tests = flights.Where(f => DateTime.Parse(f.Element("DEPARTURE_DATE").Value).Date < DateTime.Now.Date);
foreach (var test in tests)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(test.Element("DEPARTURE_DATE").Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i've got this to work - I converted your working code to VB and the syntax is different in the WHERE part of the statement